# JSSC Exception: no libjssc in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, jssc

I've had been using JSSC Connector for serial and I got the Next Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libjssc in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
at jssc.SerialNativeInterface.<clinit>(SerialNativeInterface.java:34)
at jssc.SerialPort.<init>(SerialPort.java:93)
at cl.raien.jssc.SerialExample.main(SerialExample.java:22)
```

The Code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class SerialExample {

static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SerialExample.class);

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {

log.info(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("ttyUSB0");

try {
  System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
  System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0));
  System.out.println("\"Hello World!!!\" successfully writen to port: " + serialPort.writeBytes("Hello World!!!".getBytes()));
  System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
 }
 catch (SerialPortException ex){
 System.out.println(ex);
 }
}
```

}

I'm using ubuntu 12.10  86x_64 and de jssc install the **$HOME/.jssc/linux/libjSSC-0.9_x86_64.so**

In Eclipse I setted in the **Native Library Location** of **jssc.jar** to point to that directory first. Then, I putted that file in the project root folder, as says [scream3r.org](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_Start_Working). Finally, I changed the name of the file to **libjssc** and **libjssc.so**.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think that is a maven issue, but if I didn't make work out!

[maven rxtx](http://dev.root1.de/projects/rxtx-rebundled/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

1.- Install Manually jssc.jar in maven

2.- Nothing more!! probabbly it necessary fix some issue about the natives library location in maven but in my case I haven't problem.

Comment: The link is expired

Comment: Thanks Yayo. Article in link only explained how to install jar manually in maven. Probably, there is some updated version of how do it.